# Magento2 : How to change custom status text color in admin UI Component grid

Tags: magento2, admin, grid

Change custom module status text color in magento 2 admin **UI Component** grid

Comment: text color? column bg color? or row color?

Comment: Text color eg.,if status is enabled it should be in green color and if it's disabled color should be red

Comment: Need to do this in my custom module grid

Comment: My custom grid is UI component based

Comment: Update your question that you posted as a comment.

Comment: Can't post answer because this question is 'on hold'

Comment: so sad .. is automatically change 'on hold' ???

Comment: Nope, some of the user flag this question as an unclear

Comment: ok then i have posted new question   https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/265199/how-to-change-custom-status-text-color-in-ui-component-grid-magento-2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90870/discussion-between-gomathi-and-sohel-rana).